# Using more than one consecutive while() for a single 'do' in a do...while() statement

Tags: c, do-while

I would like know the order of execution of the 'while' statements and how to arrive at the output for the following code snippets:

**SNIPPET 1:**

```
int main()
{ 
    int a;
    a=10;
    do
    while(a++<10);
    while(a++<=11);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 14

**SNIPPET 2:**

```
int main()
{ 
    int a;
    a=10;
    do
    while(a++<10);
    while(a++<=11);
    while(a++<=12);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 15

Comment: Why are you asking about/writing code like this?  The code is hard to read because none of the loops have brackets demarcating where the loop begins and ends.  If you rewrite the code with proper brackets, my guess is that it will be obvious why you arrive at the two sums.

Comment: Hint: there are more kinds of loop in C than just do-while. Perhaps you should try to find them in the code.

Comment: Use [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and everything becomes clear. Also debugging is another good way to learn the control flow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has no understanding of `c` and yet posts questions

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is probably taken from some misguided online tutorial or quiz, or, worse, homework.

Comment: 'I would like know'... why?  The code is trash and would get you fired or an 'F-' fail grade.   Code like this is of negative use to future SO users/visitors :(

Answer (score 4):

Snippet 1:

```
do
while(a++<10);
while(a++<=11);
```

can be rewritten as:

```
do {
    while(a++<10);
} while(a++<=11);
```

As `a` is `10` initially.

1. `a = 10`, condition `(a++<10) = false`, now `a = 11`
2. `a = 11`, condition `(a++<=11) = true`, now `a = 12`
3. `a = 12`, condition `(a++<10) = false`, now `a = 13`
4. `a = 13`, condition `(a++<=11) = false`,now `a = 14`

Hence `14` is printed.

---

Snippet 2 can be rewritten as

```
do {
    while(a++<10);
} while(a++<=11);
// a becomes 14 now
while(a++<=12);
```

Here the upper do-while part is similar to snippet 1, so `a` will be `14` after the do-while loop.

After that condition `(a++<=12)` will be `false` and `a` will be incremented to `15`.

Hence `15` is printed.

Note: Use braces and keep your code cleaner & easy to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do):

> *attr*(optional) **do** *statement* **while** ( *expression* ) ;

As you can see, *statement* is not optional, and you can not write `do while(ex);` — it is an error. Shortest form with empty statement is something like this: `do ; while(ex);`.

Knowing that, you can figure out that *statement* in your `do while` loop is actually a single `while`, and not an empty statement.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're not using brackets, your code isn't very clear on how the various do-while/while are executed.

Compare the following snippets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a;
    a=10;
    do { } while(a++<10);
    while(a++<=11) {}
    printf("%d",a);
} 
/* Output: 13 */
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a;
    a=10;
    do { while(a++<10); } while(a++<=11);
    printf("%d",a);
} 
/* Output: 14 */
```

So: when in doubt, use the brackets.